Calibration, Sensitivity Analysis, Numerical dispersion And Model Verification In An Ecological Model With 15 state variables
I am a student assigned to a project on improving an ecological model. This model is 1-D model consisting of a dispersive-advective component and pelagic-reaction component which was developed in R. However, I have hit a roadblock on how to calibrate, run sensitivity analysis, numerical dispersion on it for model verification. I was given a report which stated that I had to manually fine-tune the parameters, however there is no code that shows how I can do it. I tried reading the book by Karline Stoetart: "A practical guide to Ecological modelling using R as a simulation platform", unfortunately, I am not able to implement the example in the calibration section because my problem involves 15 state parameters. I have tried reading papers but they all focus on automatic calibration schemes or give very vague descriptions about the manual calibration. Does anyone know how I can go about this please or give me tips or resources how to calibrate, run a sensitivity analysis, numerical dispersion and model verification on  an ecological model with 15 state variables.
I am not able to even start model calibration.

Your supervisor should be your first point of contact in this scenario, or at least someone senior in that lab. The question appears to be more related to about model parameterization, which may get better support on a stats website like Cross Validate. Regardless, I would try to improve the question by adding more details about the model type, paramaters, and where possible, a minimal reproducible example.
